# Saleor-Storefront Error when running 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start, saleor

Trying to install **saleor storefront** on ubuntu.

After running

> npm start
>   getting the following error

```
npm start

> saleor-site@2.10.0-rc.1 start /home/nsola/storefront
> cross-env NODE_ENV=develop webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --watch --port 3000 --mode development --hotOnly

Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! saleor-site@2.10.0-rc.1 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=develop webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --watch --port 3000 --mode development --hotOnly`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the saleor-site@2.10.0-rc.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Have tried: 
Step 1: `$ npm cache clean --force`

Step 2: Delete node_modules by `$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` folder or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash. Also, delete package-lock.json file too.

Step 3: `npm install`

To start again, `$ npm start`

But did not help.

Node version: v12.16.3
NPM version: 6.14.4
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

When I installed it locally its running fine with no issues

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve this - the solution for me was to **increase the memory size**. I was running **1GB RAM on my ubuntu 18.04x64 droplet**. But after increasing it to **4GB RAM**. Everything was complying with no error.

Another solution could be by splitting "npm run  build-assets into smaller steps  where it would require low-memory systems.

Answer (score 0):

Build it by your laptop and then deploy to remote server.

https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront/issues/654#issuecomment-601150996

> ... but I would say you should rather compile everything locally with `npm run build` and then push the `dist` directory to Heroku and serve the app from there.